# 404 error laravel 4 routing

Tags: php, laravel-4, controller, routes

I am having troubles getting laravel to find a page when I route to it. My route is setup and being recognized as when I create  link using URL::route('account-create') laravel will successfully parse that into '/account/create' as to where I want the link to go to. But upon clicking it I get a 404 error.

My route

```
Route::get('/account/create', array(
     'as' => 'account-create',
     'uses' => 'AccountController@getCreate'
 ));
```

My controller

```
 class AccountController extends BaseController {


    // view the create user form
    public function getCreate() 
    {
        //return View::make('account.create');
    }


}
```

The create.blade.php is created and put inside an account folder under app/views. commenting or uncommenting makes no difference. The 404 remains.

I have also tried:

```
    Route::get('/account/create', function()
{
    return 'Hello World';
});
```

in my routes.php still the 404 remains

Is there some configuration I am missing?

Comment: Your code looks fine. Are you having trouble with all routes or just this one? Is the route for the site root working `Route::get('/', ...);`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking around some more I discovered I needed to enable rewrite_module on apache. Makes perfect sense really, how can laravel make clean urls if it cant rewrite the url. I knew it was going to be something simple to fix.

Thanks a lot for your replys

Answer (score 0):

Does navigating to `index.php/account/create` work? If so, it is probably an error in your root-level `.htaccess` file, or in your VirtualHost settings in `httpd.conf` on your server. Post the contents of `.htaccess` from `app/public`.