# laravel "subfolder" or pages that extend beyond root produce a 404 error

Tags: apache, laravel

I would like to be able to produce "subfolder" pages from within a Laravel environment. By "subfolder", I mean the subpage in the local URL localhost/subpage.

I am using Ubuntu 15.04, Apache 2.4.10, and Laravel 5.1

The document root page (on my virtual host site laravel.dev) works, and produces the expected Laravel page at the route "/".  Any calls to a path that extends beyond document root (laravel.dev/test) produce a 404 error.

Including "index.php/" within the path (laravel.dev/index.php/test) produces the expected Laravel page.  The stackoverflow question referenced below suggests that the problem is therefore likely associated with a etc/apache2/apache2.conf directive, or a .htaccess directive.

[404 error laravel 4 routing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26570147/404-error-laravel-4-routing)

The relevant part of etc/apache2/apache2.conf is

```
<Directory /home/me/Laravel/public/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

I changed allowOverride from None to All in hopes that this would allow the main Laravel .htaccess file to execute, and virtually speaking incorporate the index.php file in the path.

The relevant part of the virtual host file I created to enable the virtual host is

```
<Directory "/home/me/Laravel/public/">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
   Require all granted
</Directory>
```

The main Laravel .htaccess file is

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

This .htaccess file is untouched from the Laravel install.

As suggested in the answer to this stackoverflow question,  the RewriteRule in my .htaccess file does not have the preceding forward slash.

[Laravel 5 returns 404 error for every page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30074388/laravel-5-returns-404-error-for-every-page)

Comment: Please show your `routes.php` file.

Comment: //works
 Route::get('/', 'WelcomeController@index');
//  404 error
 Route::get('test', 'Auth\AuthController@test');
// 404 error 
 Route::get('foo/bar', function () {
  return 'Hello World';
 });

Comment: resolving it was as described in this stackoverflow question
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22757749/laravel-redirects-to-a-route-but-then-apache-gives-404-error

need to enable mod rewrite in apache
sudo a2enmod rewrite
then apache stop and restart